# EF Core: The entity type 'User' requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get EF Core up and running, but it consistently complains about my table requiring a primary key. Now the existing questions surrounding this issue haven't solved it for me.

The model:

```
public class User
{
    [Column("id")]
    public long Id { get; }
}
```

I have tried adding the `[Key]` attribute:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public long Id { get; }
}
```

I have even tried adding the `[Key]` attribute with an option:

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

After all of the attempts, I still get this error:

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'User' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'.

Comment: try to add a setter to Id

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define a setter to your property. This is because when EF Core loads the data from the DB, it constructs an object of that class, so it needs a setter to set the properties.

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

That should do the trick.